# Ruby output is different. Why?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby, and I did enough research, but couldn't understand the below. Why are these two outputs so different?

```
irb(main):007:0> puts "It's a #{"bad " * 5}world!"
It's a bad bad bad bad bad world!
=> nil


irb(main):008:0> puts "It's a #{5.times do print "bad " end}world!"
bad bad bad bad bad It's a 5world!
=> nil
```

Thanks!

Comment: `"bad " * 5` repeats the bad string 5 times, then returns that new badbadbad string, which becomes part of the "its..." string, and the whole string gets output. the other one prints bad 5 times, returns nothing to the parent string, which then gets output. e.g. the code execution path for the two versions is fundamentally different.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I understood the first one. Why does, in the second output, `5.times do print "bad " end` is printed first? Is it because '5' is an object?

Comment: When you interpolate into a string (everything inside of the `#{}`), Ruby executes that first and puts the result into the string. That's why you see it print out before the string is returned. The return value of `Fixnum#times` is the number itself, which is why you see `5` inside the string.

Comment: It's because the print expression has a side effect of printing to the screen. For instance, try `a = print 5` vs. `a = 5; print a`. In the first case, print is an expression which prints 5 to screen and evaluates to `nil` which is then stored into `a`. In the second case, `a` is 5.

Comment: That explains a lot of my other outputs. Thanks!